# Why is this addition function sometimes not working in PHP?

Tags: php, algorithm, function, math, time

I'm currently writing a class to manage time in a specific format. The output is always in this format: `0000:00:0:00:00` which stands for `YYYY:WW:D:HH:MM`.
I have a function to add time and it seemed to be working perfectly until I tried to call it several times.

I used this code to add the time, and it should have returned `0000:00:0:00:42` but it returned `0000:00:0:03:60`.

Here's my full class. **Code Demo on https://3v4l.org/YiEQF**

```html
<?php

namespace Core\component\time;

final class TimeFactory {

    /** @var int */
    private $year;
    /** @var int */
    private $weekNumber;
    /** @var int */
    private $day;
    /** @var int */
    private $hour;
    /** @var int */
    private $minute;

    /**
     * @param string $formatted
     * @return static
     */
    public static function createFromString(string $formatted): self {
        if (!preg_match('/^(\d{4}):(\d{2}):(\d{1}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})$/', $formatted, $matches)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Invalid currency format.');
        }
        return new self(...array_slice($matches, 1));
    }

   
    /**
     * TimeFactory constructor.
     * @param int $year
     * @param int $weekNumber
     * @param int $day
     * @param int $hour
     * @param int $minute
     */
    public function __construct(int $year, int $weekNumber, int $day, int $hour, int $minute)
    {
        $this->year = $year;
        $this->weekNumber = $weekNumber;
        $this->day = $day;
        $this->hour = $hour;
        $this->minute = $minute;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $addedYears
     * @return bool
     */
    public function addYears(int $addedYears): bool {
        $newYears = $this->year + $addedYears;
        if($newYears > 9999) {
            return false;
        } else {
            $this->year += $newYears;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $addedWeeks
     */
    public function addWeeks(int $addedWeeks): void {
        $newWeeks = $this->weekNumber + $addedWeeks;
        if($newWeeks >= 52) {
            $years = round($newWeeks / 52, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
            $this->addYears($years);
        }
        $this->weekNumber += $newWeeks % 52;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $addedDays
     */
    public function addDays(int $addedDays): void {
        $newDays = $this->day + $addedDays;
        if($newDays >= 7) {
            $weeks = round($newDays / 7, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
            $this->addWeeks($weeks);
        }
        $this->day += $newDays % 7;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $addedHours
     */
    public function addHours(int $addedHours): void {
        $newHours = $this->hour + $addedHours;
        if($newHours >= 24) {
            $days = round($newHours / 24, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
            $this->addDays($days);
        }
        $this->hour += $newHours % 24;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $addedMinutes
     */
    public function addMinutes(int $addedMinutes): void {
        $newMinutes = $this->minute + $addedMinutes;
        if($newMinutes >= 60) {
            $hours = round($newMinutes / 60, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
            $this->addHours($hours);
        }
        $this->minute += $newMinutes % 60;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getYears(): int {
        return $this->year;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getWeeks(): int {
        return $this->weekNumber;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getDays(): int {
        return $this->day;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getHours(): int {
        return $this->hour;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getMinutes(): int {
        return $this->minute;
    }

    public function reduceTime(Int $amount, String $type) : bool {
        switch($type) {
            case "m":
                if($this->getMinutes() >= $amount) {
                    $this->minute -= $amount;
                    return true;
                } else {
                    if($this->getHours() > 0) {
                        $this->hour -= 1;
                        $minutesToAdd = 60 - $amount;
                        $this->addMinutes($minutesToAdd);
                        return true;
                    } elseif ($this->getDays() > 0) {
                        $this->day -= 1;
                        $hoursToAdd = 23;
                        $minutesToAdd = 60 - $amount;
                        $this->addHours($hoursToAdd);
                        $this->addMinutes($minutesToAdd);
                        return true;
                    } elseif ($this->getWeeks() > 0) {
                        $this->weekNumber -= 1;
                        $daysToAdd = 6;
                        $hoursToAdd = 23;
                        $minutesToAdd = 60 - $amount;
                        $this->addDays($daysToAdd);
                        $this->addHours($hoursToAdd);
                        $this->addMinutes($minutesToAdd);
                        return true;
                    }  elseif ($this->getYears() > 0) {
                        $this->year -= 1;
                        $weeksToAdd = 51;
                        $daysToAdd = 6;
                        $hoursToAdd = 23;
                        $minutesToAdd = 60 - $amount;
                        $this->addWeeks($weeksToAdd);
                        $this->addDays($daysToAdd);
                        $this->addHours($hoursToAdd);
                        $this->addMinutes($minutesToAdd);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                break;
            case "h":
                if($this->getHours() >= $amount) {
                    $this->hour -= $amount;
                    return true;
                } else {
                    if ($this->getDays() > 0) {
                        $this->day -= 1;
                        $hoursToAdd = 24 - $amount;
                        $this->addHours($hoursToAdd);
                        return true;
                    } elseif ($this->getWeeks() > 0) {
                        $this->weekNumber -= 1;
                        $daysToAdd = 6;
                        $hoursToAdd = 24 - $amount;
                        $this->addDays($daysToAdd);
                        $this->addHours($hoursToAdd);
                        return true;
                    }  elseif ($this->getYears() > 0) {
                        $this->year -= 1;
                        $weeksToAdd = 51;
                        $daysToAdd = 6;
                        $hoursToAdd = 24 - $amount;
                        $this->addWeeks($weeksToAdd);
                        $this->addDays($daysToAdd);
                        $this->addHours($hoursToAdd);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                break;
            case "d":
                if($this->getDays() >= $amount) {
                    $this->day -= $amount;
                    return true;
                } else {
                    if ($this->getWeeks() > 0) {
                        $this->weekNumber--;
                        $daysToAdd = 7 - $amount;
                        $this->addDays($daysToAdd);
                        return true;
                    } elseif ($this->getYears() > 0) {
                        $this->year--;
                        $weeksToAdd = 51;
                        $daysToAdd = 7 - $amount;
                        $this->addWeeks($weeksToAdd);
                        $this->addDays($daysToAdd);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                break;
            case "w":
                if($this->getWeeks() >= $amount) {
                    $this->weekNumber -= $amount;
                    return true;
                } else {
                    if ($this->getYears() > 0) {
                        $weeksToAdd = 52 - $amount;
                        $this->addWeeks($weeksToAdd);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                break;
            case "y":
                if($this->getYears() >= $amount) {
                    $this->year -= $amount;
                    return true;
                }
        }
        return false;
    }
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function __toString(): string {
        return sprintf('%04d:%02d:%d:%02d:%02d', $this->year, $this->weekNumber, $this->day, $this->hour, $this->minute);
    }
}
$factory = TimeFactory::createFromString("0000:00:0:00:00");
$factory->addMinutes(2);
$factory->addMinutes(4);
$factory->addMinutes(6);
$factory->addMinutes(8);
$factory->addMinutes(10);
$factory->addMinutes(12);

echo $factory;
echo "\n" . $factory->getMinutes();
echo "\n" . $factory->getHours();
echo "\n" . $factory->getDays();
echo "\n" . $factory->getWeeks();
echo "\n" . $factory->getYears();
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: So the `WW` part is supposed to be what - the week number? Then why are you writing your own class for this in the first place - and not using PHP’s DateTime? Showing the week number of a date is just a matter of _output formatting_ after all.

Comment: @04FS I used the DateTime class before but it can't display zero time.

Comment: And yes, WW is the week number.

Comment: _“but it can't display zero time”_ - meaning what exactly?

Comment: @04FS PHP's `DateTime` class can't display zero time because it follows the calender format. Though, my time will need to start from zero and the DateTime class can't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if the overall process is the best method of achieving what you want, but this is the problem ( I think ).

Just using the minute code as an example...

```
public function addMinutes(int $addedMinutes): void {
    $newMinutes = $this->minute + $addedMinutes;
    if($newMinutes >= 60) {
        $hours = round($newMinutes / 60, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
        $this->addHours($hours);
    }
    $this->minute += $newMinutes % 60;
}
```

So first you add the new minutes to the existing time...

```
$newMinutes = $this->minute + $addedMinutes;
```

process the hour rollover and then you add the new minutes field again...

```
$this->minute += $newMinutes % 60;
```

This is repeated at each layer.

So I suggest something like

```
public function addMinutes(int $addedMinutes): void {
    $newMinutes = $this->minute + $addedMinutes;
    if($newMinutes >= 60) {
        $hours = floor($newMinutes / 60);
        $this->addHours($hours);
        $newMinutes -= ($hours * 60);
    }
    $this->minute = $newMinutes;
}
```

This does similar processing, but the last part is just assigning the new minutes, rather than adding them again.

Note that I've also changed the way that the next level is calculated - using `floor()` instead of `round()`.

Comment: That works, but when I  try to add 400 minutes, I get back `0000:00:0:07:-20`.

Comment: I've updated the code - changed the line `$hours = floor($newMinutes / 60);` as `floor()` is (IMHO) the proper way of doing this bit.

Comment: Awesome, that worked again.  Thank you so much for your time and help, that saved me a lot of frustration.